# Spring, validate all header parameters and error out once

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

Would it be possible to validate all header parameters once and return the validation message for all required parameters instead of Spring returning field by field errors?

Example: If I don't pass two header parameters in the request below, Spring returns a first field error. I need an error message for both parameters at once.

```java
public String handleRequestByTwoHeaders(@RequestHeader(value="Header1",required=true) String header1, @RequestHeader(value="Header2",required=true) String header2) {

}
```

O/P: "message": "Required request header 'Header1' for method parameter type String is not present",

Although we can read the values and do the null check, but my Swagger-UI does not display the mandatory field(*), if I do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue, the tricky part is to keep displaying the mandatory field(*) in Swagger-UI.

I came up with the following:

declaring `requiredHeaders`:

```
private List<String> requiredHeaders = new ArrayList<String>(){{
  add("Header1");
  add("Header2");
}};
```

Using `@ApiImplicitParams` for Swagger-UI:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Header1", paramType = "header", required = true),
  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Header2", paramType = "header", required = true)
})
@PostMapping
public Object handleRequestByTwoHeaders(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {

  // modify this part for the response body of your need
  List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
  for(String s : requiredHeaders){
      if(!headers.containsKey(s) messages.add(s + " not found in header.");
  }

  if(messages.size() > 0) return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(messages);
  return "OK";
}
```

One downside is that there is no correlation between `requiredHeaders` and `@ApiImplicitParams`. Modification is needed for both fields whenever update is required.

Hope it can help a bit.

Comment: Its not working :     "message": "Required request header 'headers' for method parameter type HttpHeaders is not present",

Comment: Sorry but can you share your code? I failed to replicate the same response.

Comment: I tried with the same code you provided